# Marionette regions and layout

Tags: marionette

I have following code to put a view inside a region.

```
Layout.rightPanel.show(new changePasswordView());
```

How do I close this view as I don't have access to id?

Also it creates an empty `div` while rendering view. Is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the `close` method:

```
Layout.rightPanel.close();
```

The only way to avoid having an extra div is to declare an enclosing tag with the `tagName` attribute in your view. For example, having `tagName: "p"` in your view will make your view get rendered within a "p" tag instead of a "div".